# How to encode decode between js and java?

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am working on a project in that java script as front-end and java as back-end are used, my problem is that I want to pass some string using restangular calls to my back-end resources. If passing parameter have space between the string then I got **500 (Server Error)** before reaching to back-end resource side.

Lets take example :

At Java Script : RESTangular call

```
var myRestCall= Restangular.all('myRoot/myMethod/'+myLocalPath+'/'+folderName);
restPSTFolders.getList().then(function(listPSTFolders){
//my stuff
});
```

At Java Resource :

```
  @ApiOperation(value = "My Method",
                notes = "Returns My Method list",
                responseContainer = "List",
                response = List.class)
   @Path("/myMethod/{myLocalPath}/{folderName}")
   @GET
   @Transactional
   @Timed
   public List myMethod(@PathParam("myLocalPath") String myLocalPath, @PathParam("folderName") String sFolderName) {
       //my stuff
    }
```

In my example `myLocalPath` parameter can have spaces and special characters in the string as it can be any :

- C:\MY DRIVE\My Path One\My Path
- D:\My favorite

To pass this to back-end class from RESTangular call, I need to replace all spaces with some character, it work for me, but I am not thinking its a good way to encode the special character and space with any character because the replacing character can also be a part of existing path then at back-end on again replacing the character, might change the path.

EDIT : If I passed the parameter as json object:

```
var parameterJsonPath = {};
parameterJsonPath={"myLocalPath": pathValue};

var myRestCall= Restangular.all('myRoot/myMethod/'+parameterJsonPath+'/'+folderName);
```

Does not make any sense as I got : **../myRoot/myMethod/%5Bobject%20Object%5D Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Server Error)**

And making the parameterJsonPath to `JSON.stringify(parameterJsonPath);` will pass this as string that of no use for me.

Thus in all, is there any good way to encode the special character of string in js, so at back-end side I could decode that string using same key that were used while encoding?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp.htm